# iPhone keyboard hides text when entering on contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, contenteditable

My website has a contenteditable div like below:

```
<p id="" contenteditable="true">Text here</p>
```

It works fine on most browsers and android, but on iPhone safari, when I enter more and more text (or press a few "return" key), the cursor will fall outside of the visible area. The keyboard will hide the cursor and I don;t know what I am typing.

The expected behavior should be the page to be scrolled up automatically when I enter text. Can I fix it on my HTML codes or by some JavaScript? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Safari, you should submit a bug report to Apple:

https://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html